# Not able to store multiple record on Localstorage plus retrieve it to display back on page - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am in trouble, I am adding simple field input data and displaying it on page, it working fine but on page refresh it just disappeared, so i tried to use local storage, i tried few things i store my whole object in Storage, i tried to Store single values but in both cases it replacing old data with new record and i am not able to Store multiple records.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izVg8.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC2wa.jpg)

<------------------------------------------------------------------------>

```
function Book (title, author, type){

    this. title = title;
    this. author = author;
    this. type = type;
}
// display 
function Display(){

}
//add method to display function 
Display.prototype.add = function(book){

    //console.log('adding to ');
    let tablebody  = document.getElementById('tablebody');
   let UIstring = `<tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>${book.title}</td>
                    <td>${book.author}</td>
                    <td>${book.type}</td>
                  </tr>
                 
    </tbody>` 
    
    tablebody.innerHTML += UIstring; 

}



    Display.prototype.clear = function(){

    let clearform = document.getElementById('collogelibrary');
    clearform.reset();
}

 Display.prototype.validate = function(book){

   if(book.title.length <2 || book.author.length < 2){

    return false;

   }else {

    return true;

   }
}

Display.prototype.show = function(type, displaymessage){

  let message = document.getElementById('message');
  message.innerHTML = `
  <div class="alert alert-${type} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <strong>Message!</strong> ${displaymessage}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    `

   setInterval(() => {
     message.innerHTML = '';
   }, 2000);
}

//submit form function

let libraryform = document.getElementById("collogelibrary");
libraryform.addEventListener('submit', Libraryformsubmit);


function Libraryformsubmit(event){
 //event.preventDefault();

  title = document.getElementById('bookname').value;
  author = document.getElementById('author').value;

  fiction = document.getElementById('fiction');
  gardening = document.getElementById('gardening');
  programming = document.getElementById('computer')

 //let library = [title, author];
 //console.log(library);
 //let type = document.getElementById('');

 let type;

  if (fiction.checked){

    type = fiction.value;

  }else if (gardening.checked){

    type = gardening.value;

  }else if (programming.checked){

    type = programming.value;

  }
 
let library, library1;

 //localStorage.setItem('library', title);
 //localStorage.setItem('library1', author);

 //JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(library));
 //JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(library1));

 let book = new Book (title, author, type); // book object
let display = new Display(); //dipaly object
if (display.validate(book)){

  display.add(book);

  localStorage.setItem('book', JSON.stringify(book));
  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(book));

//console.log(mybook);
 display.show('success', 'your book has added');
 display.clear();


} else {

  display.show('danger', 'your book has not added');
}
//display.add(book);
//display.clear();

event.preventDefault();
 //console.log(book);

}
```

<--------------------------------HTML------------------------------->

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<!---Nav Bar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Punjab Library</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>

            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="searchTxt" type="search" placeholder="Search"
                    aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--End of nav br-->

    <div id="message"></div>

    <!--Div Container-->
    
    <div class="container my-3">
        <h3>Punjab Library</h3>
        <hr>

        <form id="collogelibrary">
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="Book Name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Book Name</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bookname" placeholder="book name">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="Author" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Author</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="author" placeholder="author">
              </div>
            </div>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Type</legend>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="fiction" value="Fiction" checked>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
                      Fiction
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="computer" value="Computer">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
                      Computer
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="gardening" value="Gardening" >
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
                      Gardening
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-sm-2">Checkbox</div>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck1">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                    Example checkbox
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Book</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          <div id="table">
            <h3>Your Books</h3>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Author</th>
                    <th scope="col">Type</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tablebody">
                  <tr>
                   
                    
                  </tr>
                 
                </tbody>
              </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  


    <!--end of Container-->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

localstorage.setItem() will replace the entire old value inside the localstorage, to avoid this error use below code snippet.

```
var allBooks = [];
var bookArr = localstorage.getItem('book');
if (bookArr !== null) {
    allBooks = JSON.parse(bookArr);
}
allBooks.add(newBook);

localstorage.setItem('book', JSON.stringfy(allBooks));

localstorage.getItem('book'); // [{...}, {...}, {...}]
```

Comment: I could not understand it. if you can please see my code file and make changes in that.. that would be good. Thanks.